# Adding a row to another row

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the firstname and lastname rows together in one row.
This is the code I have so far ,

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, department FROM tl_member ORDER BY firstname LIMIT 29";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><br><hr><th align='left'>Naam</th><th align='left'>telefoon<th align='left'>phone</th><th>afdeling</tr>";
// output data in rows
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "<tr><td>" .$row["firstname"]."</td><td>" .$row["lastname"]."</td><td>" .$row["phone"]."</td><td>" .$row["department"]."</tr>";
    }               
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

the firstname and lastname are now shows seperatly I want them to be together as one ?

Comment: This is more a HTML question, since its related to tables. Just remove the `</td> <td>` between the first and last name, and add a `blank space`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there! You just needed to place first name and second name in the same td

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "</td><td>" . $row["phone"] . "</td><td>" . $row["department"] . "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, department FROM tl_member ORDER BY firstname LIMIT 29";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><br><hr><th align='left'>Naam</th><th align='left'>telefoon<th align='left'>phone</th><th>afdeling</tr>";
// output data in rows
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "<tr><td>" .$row["firstname"]." " .$row["lastname"]."</td><td>" .$row["phone"]."</td><td>" .$row["department"]."</tr>";
    }               
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Huum..

Like that ?

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, department FROM tl_member ORDER BY firstname LIMIT 29";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><br><hr><th align='left'>Naam</th><th align='left'>telefoon<th  align='left'>phone</th><th>afdeling</tr>";
// output data in rows
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<tr><td>" .$row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]."</td><td>" .$row["phone"]."</td><td>" .$row["department"]."</tr>";
}               
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean in the same row/cell? Like this?

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" .$row["firstname"] . $row["lastname"]."</td><td>" .$row["phone"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["department"]."</tr>";
}
```

Comment: you forgot in your code to close a `<td>` after last name.

Answer (score 0):

write the query in this manner :

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, department,concat(firstname,'',lastname) fullname FROM tl_member ORDER BY firstname LIMIT 29";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

to get fullname you need to use: $row["fullname"]